# Should I use Array with a Maximum limit or an ArrayList for Vertex Batching in OpenGL?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to batch the vertices of objects in my game and draw them with a single draw call. However, I don't know how many of these objects I'll draw before hand and hence the number of vertices is not known.

Should I use an array with a large size or just go with a List? I am getting better performance when using arrays, but the size might be more than what i really need which might lead to a higher memory usage.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible method for dynamically array resizing is *array doubling*.

Each time you need to increase the array size, reallocate the double of its current size. 
Start with a small value, e.g. `16 = 2^4` (or one that suits your use case).

If you now have `513 = 2^9+1` till `1024 = 2^10` vertices, the array increase operation was called at most six times.

Comment: A  Really Simple and Efficient Solution! I tried and array doubling seems to be faster than an ArrayList! Thank You!

Comment: Glad I could help :-)